# the variable 'cc' appears to change size on every loop iteration matlab

Tags: matlab, tarjans-algorithm

I have this code source for tarjan program with Matlab , this error appears when I run the prog , how can I fix it

```
function [C, S, idx, index, index_accessible] = strongconnect(C, G, v, S, idx, index,       index_accessible)
index(v) = idx;
index_accessible(v) = idx;
idx = idx+1;
S = push(S,v); %ajouter le sommet courant à la pile

% Liste les sommets adjacents au sommet courant
n = voisin(G,v);

% Parcours récursif
for i = 1:length(n)
    if(index(n(i)) == 0)
        [C, S, idx, index, index_accessible] = strongconnect(C, G, n(i), S, idx, index,  index_accessible);
        index_accessible(v) = min(index_accessible(v), index_accessible(n(i)));
    elseif (~isempty(find(S == n(i), 1)))
        index_accessible(v) = min(index_accessible(v), index(n(i)));
    end
end

% Le sommet est une racine, on calcule la composante fortement connexe associée
if(index_accessible(v) == index(v))
    cc = []; %composante fortement connexe issue du sommet
    if(~isempty(S))
        [tmp, S] = pop(S);
        cc = [cc tmp];
    end
    while(~isempty(S) && tmp ~= v)
        [tmp, S] = pop(S);
        ***cc*** = [cc tmp];
    end
    if(~isempty(cc))
        % Les composantes connexes n'ont pas toutes
        % la même longueur. On complète donc la ligne
        % avec des 0.
        C = [C ; cc zeros(1,size(G,1) - length(cc))];
    end
end
end
```

the problem is with the cc between stars

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Preallocating cc will make the code run faster. If you know the size of cc in the line `cc = []` you could initialize cc with something like `cc = nan(5,1)`. This will create an array with size 5 which is filled later.

Comment: I'm still a beginner in matlab, I want a source code for the algorithm of Tarjan with matlab, I find the code in this link [link](http://glotin.univ-tln.fr/graphes/graphtook/tarjan.html), I could not execute the code, I thought the problem is with the cc but since it's just a warning so it is not the main error. can you tell me how can I run these lines of code, and what is the command line and the input that I have enter to have a result, thank you very much

Comment: I rolled back the question edit as it had removed all relevant information for the question. Make sure the question remains clear, even if you already have an answer.

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT ALTER OLD QUESTIONS THAT HAVE BEEN ANSWERED INTO NEW QUESTIONS** - ask a new question instead! Please undo your edit!

Comment: @user3281660: To understand this question, one has to know the previous one. I suggest to start over with a new question. Include the input, output and code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the code. The input is a graph matrix, I used a random generated one:

```
G=randi(10,20,20)==1;
```

Now call the function:

```
C=tarjan(G);
```

Each row of C contains one component.

If this does not answer your question, please update it including a error description and your input data.

Comment: yes it is good Daniel, I made this little test on adjacency matrix and I got this matrix  the problem is that I do not understand how to read to determine the strongly connected components can m help

Comment: Each row of C contains the indices of one connected component.

Comment: I update the post with the current problem take a look

Comment: @user3281660: Don't do that! Now the answer Daniel gave makes no sense any more.